# Is it possible to access windows applications gui with lua or python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, user-interface, lua

I'm coming from js world, so i suppose that i can access input fields like in js, or add options to context menu.
I tried pynput and keyboard module for python, but tahts a weird, and not so handy solution. How to access this layer of system?

Comment: so u want to have interactions with input field which is accomplished by js showing on a web page?

Comment: Search for "UI automation".

Comment: Yes, access input fields on windows like js with dom.

Comment: And how to listen input events? Get content of input? Ui automation tolls not provide thes options, or am i wrong?